# How to use private key

Tags: java, key, private, using

In my search i found out  that we can generate private key called myrsakey.pem.What is the purpose of this key where this key is used.Help me.

Regards
Sharun.

Comment: What did you search for, to get information about private keys, but not on their usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Hi i want to use myrsakey.pem in my
>   java program for authentication

Why? If you don't know how? Where did this requirement come from?

Ask for clarification. Are they talking about digital signatures for example? or X.509?

Answer (score 1):

It is a key used to perform RSA encryption. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA

Comment: Hi i want to use myrsakey.pem in my java program for authentication, But i dont know where and how to use it.